# Difference between finite and infinite for dimension of sum of vector subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reviewing *Advanced Linear Algebra* by Steve Roman.  He says that for subspaces $S$ and $T$ of vector space $V$

$$\dim(S)+\dim(T) = \dim(S+T) + \dim(S \cap T)$$

but we cannot write

$$\dim(S+T) = \dim(S)+\dim(T) -\dim(S \cap T)$$

unless $S+T$ is finite-dimensional.

I am trying to reason out why that is.  If $S+T$ has infinite dimension, then one of these subspaces has infinite dimension.  Actually, I think bases for both subspaces have to have the same cardinality, since otherwise $S+T$ does not seem well-defined.  However, perhaps this is where I am wrong.  Assuming you can somehow define the operation $S+T$ for this situation, I see three cases.

Without loss of generality, if $S$ has finite dimension, then I don't see a problem.  In the second equation, you would simply get that the cardinalities of the bases for $T$ and $S+T$ are the same (assuming a constant added to infinity is infinity).

If both subspaces have the same infinite dimension, then I suppose you would get $\infty - \infty = \infty$, which is a problem.

If both subspaces have infinite dimension but their bases have different cardinalities, then I don't see a problem here either.  Let $n$ be the larger cardinality and $m$ be the smaller cardinality.  I assume $n-m=n$ as in the situation where $n=\infty$ and $m$ is a constant.  Then we arrive at a similar situation as in the first case.

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: The sum of two subspaces is the set of vectors that can be expressed as the sum of two vectors, one from each subspace. They do not have to have the same bases. For example, if $S$ and $T$ are both subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$, with $S$ equal to the span of $\{ (1,0,0) \}$, and $T$ equal to the span of $\{ (0,1,0), (0,0,1) \}$, their bases are not the same.

Comment: I see, but when dealing with infinite dimensions, is it possible for the basis of $S+T$ to have greater cardinality than the bases of $S$ and $T$?  If so, then there are more cases to consider.

Comment: I have almost no experience with vector spaces that have an uncountable basis, but it seems to me that if the two subspaces have bases $\mathcal{B}_S$ and  $\mathcal{B}_T$, then $S+T$ would be the span of $\mathcal{B}_S \cup \mathcal{B}_T$, so the dimension of $S+T$, if infinite, cannot be larger than the dimensions of both $S$ and $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is with $\infty- \infty$ which is not defined in general.

Indeed, if $S+T$ is infinite-dimensional then at least one of $S$ and $T$ are infinite-dimensional. Namely, if they were both finite-dimensional with bases $\{s_1, \ldots, s_m\}$ and $\{t_1, \ldots, t_n\}$ respectively then $S+T$ is spanned by $\{s_1, \ldots, s_m, t_1, \ldots, t_n\}$, and hence it is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks, am I also right in assuming that if the bases of the subspaces have different infinite cardinalities (e.g. countable and uncountable) then $S+T$ is not well-defined?

Comment: @Pareod The $\infty$ notation basically ignores different infinite cardinalities. It only means that the set is infinite. The only problem with the second equation is $\infty - \infty$. Your understanding in the last paragraph is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed the $\infty-\infty$ on the right-hand side, and nothing else, that stops you from doing your rewriting. Subtraction of infinities (in particular cardinalities) is a murky notion, and best avoided entirely.